# How can I make HTML read empty space in a paragraph?

Tags: html, ascii-art

I am trying to include some of my ASCII Art in my website. This is my code as it is shown in my editor (Brackets):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
         <p style="font-family: Courier New;">
                 _<br/>
                (@)\____________________  _<br/>
                |-|                     \(@)<br/>
                | |                      |-|<br/>
                |-|                      | |<br/>
                |_|                      |-|<br/>
                (@)\____________________ |_|<br/>
                 ~                      \(@)<br/>
                                          ~
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, viewing it using the Live Preview button, all the spaces with nothing behind them are ignored, causing the ASCII Art to look terrible.

Is there any way to make the browser read these spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press and hold “Alt” key and while holding it, type digit keys 255 at the numeric keypad, this should print out an invisible character; which should fix your problem.

Comment: Brilliant! Where did you learn that? Works even on my _ancient_ PC!

Comment: @Kslkgh It has been around sense the character map was created. I even know of some people who have remapped their space bar to that character.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `<pre>` tag. Check it out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Comment: `<pre></pre>` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You would need to replace the spaces with `&nbsp;`